# query to fetch duplicate rows with a condition that when rows are duplicate and the column contains NULL values.

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    TreatableComments, Category, Comment_Date, Comment_Time, Reported_Url
FROM
    TestData.dbo.CXA
GROUP BY 
    TreatableComments, Category, Comment_Date, Comment_time, Reported_Url
HAVING 
    COUNT(TreatableComments) > 1 AND Category IS NULL
```

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY`  if you're not using any aggregtation operators (like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`) etc?

Comment: As soon as I am using category column in group by it is giving me no results.

Comment: What is this query doing, what do you want it to be doing, and what's not working?

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Comment: Remove category from `group by`. In `having` say `and count(case when Category is null then 1 end) > 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your question doesn't have a database system tag I thought I would give this a quick try in SQL Server (2016):

```
--Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (TreatableComments VARCHAR(50), Category VARCHAR(50), CommentDate DATE, Reported_Url VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 'Stuff', 'Category 1', '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'More Stuff', 'Category 2', '20180103', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Same', NULL, '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Same', NULL, '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com';

--Query
SELECT
    TreatableComments,
    Category,
    CommentDate,
    Reported_Url
FROM
    @table
GROUP BY
    TreatableComments,
    Category,
    CommentDate,
    Reported_Url
HAVING
    COUNT(TreatableComments) > 1
    AND Category IS NULL;
```

When I run that it works, i.e. it gives me a single row:

```
TreatableComments   Category    CommentDate Reported_Url
Same                NULL        2018-01-01  stackoverflow.com
```

So this means that either your data looks very different to mine, and you don't have any duplicates with a NULL Category, or you are using a database that works differently to SQL Server in this regard, which tbh seems rather unlikely, as this is very vanilla SQL.

---

Seeing as what you actually wanted is completely different from your original question, here's a new answer:

```
--Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (TreatableComments VARCHAR(50), Category VARCHAR(50), CommentDate DATE, Reported_Url VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 'Stuff', 'Category 1', '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'More Stuff', 'Category 2', '20180103', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Same', 'A', '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Same', NULL, '20180101', 'stackoverflow.com';

--Query
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    @table t
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        TreatableComments,
        CommentDate,
        Reported_Url
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        TreatableComments,
        CommentDate,
        Reported_Url
    HAVING
        COUNT(TreatableComments) > 1) d ON d.TreatableComments = t.TreatableComments AND d.CommentDate = t.CommentDate AND t.Reported_Url = d.Reported_Url
WHERE
    t.Category IS NULL;
```

This works by finding cases where there are duplicates, then joining back to the main table and only picking rows where the category is `NULL`.

New results are:

```
TreatableComments   Category    CommentDate Reported_Url
Same            NULL            2018-01-01  stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Richard,  in my table I have two columns TreatableComments and Category. My question is i want to select the row on a condition where TreatableComments contains duplicate data lets say in row 1 and 2 treatableComments contain ABC and ABC and in category column in one row it is X and in another it is NULL i want to pick only the row which has NULL in the category.

Comment: Great, so now I understand what you actually want I edited my question to give a different answer.